# How to use a function to get from tablename in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, function, select, tablename

thanks for help.
Sorry for bad english.

I created a function to return a tablename, for use in my select statement, here the script of function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getfromtable(objecttype varchar, destinationtable varchar, firstdate date, OUT tablename varchar)
AS $BODY$
declare 
 objectType       ALIAS FOR $1;
 destinationTable ALIAS FOR $2;
 firstDate        ALIAS FOR $3;
 --tableResult varchar;
BEGIN
   IF UPPER(objectType) = 'VIEW' THEN
      select destinationTable || to_char(cast(firstDate as date),'yy') into tablename;
   END IF;
   IF UPPER(objectType) = 'TABLE' THEN
      select destinationTable || to_char(cast(firstDate as date),'mmyy') into tablename;
   END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I need use this function, because i have table names with MMYY or views with YY in name ... the function works correctly, but, i need to use it in select, for example:

```
select * from getfromtable('TABLE','tab_venda_',current_date)
```

But, here is my problem, if i execute the script, the postgres return the table name, but not execute a select from a table ... i need execute a select in a table, not return the function...

How I wish it were

```
select * from tab_venda_0319
```

Whats i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How do you wish to execute those queries? Inside PL/pgSQL function body? Or using some language that is connecting to database and could make use of dynamic SQL? Because you need dynamic SQL for this to work and plain SQL does not support those.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński i want execute it in PL/pgSQL ... 
Below some examples of table names:
tab_venda0319, tab_venda0219, tab_venda0119
movprodd19, movprodd18, vdadet0119, vdadet0219 ..

I want execute a function or any other solution to get a table name using the prefix table: select * from getfromtable('TABLE','tab_venda_',current_date) if i want: select * form tab_venda_0319

Comment: I'm a bit too short on time to do something that would qualify IMO as an answer, but documentation has excellent section about dynamic SQL, including easy to understand examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Unrelated, but: `objectType       ALIAS FOR $1;` is useless as your first parameter is already named `objectType`

Answer (score 0):

You are not really doing something wrong, but functions just do not work that way. What the function returns is not a table name, but a value (parsing and query plan buildung are already done at that point).

Perhaps [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) might help you?

Comment: Sorry for bad english, thanks for answer!

The partitioning not help me... The tables names are created by system, and the system is working in production environment. 
My function get correct table name, but not make a select * from :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the table name you can return the query result. See modified function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getfromtable(objecttype varchar, destinationtable varchar, firstdate date) 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
AS $BODY$
declare 
 objectType       ALIAS FOR $1;
 destinationTable ALIAS FOR $2;
 firstDate        ALIAS FOR $3;
 tablename varchar;
BEGIN
   IF UPPER(objectType) = 'VIEW' THEN
      select destinationTable || to_char(cast(firstDate as date),'yy') into tablename;
   END IF;
   IF UPPER(objectType) = 'TABLE' THEN
      select destinationTable || to_char(cast(firstDate as date),'mmyy') into tablename;
   END IF;
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '||tablename;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

While selecting you need to provide the column list for this to work as below

```
SELECT * FROM getfromtable('TABLE','tab_venda_',current_date) AS tab(column1_name column1_type, ...);
```

Comment: I need pass the all columns name and type in statement SELECT * FROM getfromtable('TABLE','tab_venda_',current_date) AS t(col1_name col1_type, ...); ?

Comment: yes you need to mention all the columns and its type.

Comment: It's hard, this is a ERP system and some table have 30 - 50 columns, and the system is under constant atualization.

Comment: @NycolasMerino  If you plan on using that data within PL/pgSQL function then I think it would be better to just return table name and EXECUTE query within function that does something with data. It will not require listing columns and their types. I think that SRF might still have performance issue that requires function to get full result before it starts returning it, with might use up some memory or disk space and cause problems if table is large enough.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Thanks for answer, sorry for bad english. I can not simply put the table name and execute, because the script was executed weekly, when the month change, i need edit the table name for new month. The query is executed in PL/pgSQL, however it's is automatic for show in a dashboard.